# overloading typecast operator

Tags: c++, c++11

Overloaded typecast operator int, but after compiling and running the code I get segmentation fault.

I debugged my program and saw that line of code where typecast is used repeats without ending, every time calling typecast function itself. So, can anyone explain what's going on around there ?

```
/* IN HEADER */
class ComplexNumber
{
private:
    double m_real, m_imaginary;

public:
    ComplexNumber(double real = 0.0, double imaginary = 0.0);
    ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber &obj);

    ComplexNumber& operator= (const ComplexNumber &obj);

    operator int();

};

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary): 
    m_real(real), m_imaginary(imaginary)
{

}

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber &obj): 
m_real(obj.m_real), m_imaginary(obj.m_imaginary)
{

}

ComplexNumber& ComplexNumber::operator= (const ComplexNumber &obj)
{
    m_real = obj.m_real;
    m_imaginary = obj.m_imaginary;

    return *this;
}

ComplexNumber::operator int()
{
    m_real = static_cast<int>(m_real);
    m_imaginary = static_cast<int>(m_imaginary);

    return *this;
}

/* IN MAIN */
ComplexNumber obj(3.4, 5.6);

obj = static_cast<int>(obj);
//here it gives seg fault
```

Comment: `operator int` should return an int. Perhaps you want something like `ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::clamp() { return ComplexNumber(static_cast<int>(m_real), static_cast<int>(m_imaginary)); }`?

Comment: @Artyer it's same as *this, gives seg fault error. I hope you meant operator int() instead of clamp().

Answer (score 3):

In the `return *this;` of the `ComplexNumber::operator int()` function, `*this` is a `ComplexNumber`. Since the function must return `int`, the `return` causes a conversion to `int`.

Thus, we have an implicit conversion of `ComplexNumber` to `int`, which causes `ComplexNumber::operator int()` to be called.

Comment: thanks for explanation, so how can I solve it that it will not do that conversions repeatedly  ? I want that typecast function to change the values of object and return it, but when I return object itself it still typecasts.

Comment: And thus, infinity.

Comment: @BejanMuhidinov: Defining a conversion function is for converting an object to an `int`. It is not for converting things in the object to `int` values. To do that, just define a normal function with a name you choose, like `ToLatticePoint`, that returns a `ComplexNumber` with the desired values in its components.

Comment: @EricPostpischil oow, I got it now, was thinking that conversion function is for converting things in the object to int. Thanks a lot for explanation !